# Reactive Banana: how to use values from a remote API and merge them in the event stream

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

I am using Reactive-Banana in a WX interface.
I need to retrieve a value from an external service API when a button is pressed.

I have a generic `Behavior` based on the data type `AppState` that “accums” the transformed changes based on a function transformation (`doSomeTransformation`). The values that get transformed are transported by the events and they come from a remote API (`getRemoteValue`) when a button on the interface is pressed. I have written a slim version of the code that represents the essential part:

```hs
module Main where

{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-} -- allows "forall t. Moment t"

import Graphics.UI.WX hiding (Event)
import Reactive.Banana
import Reactive.Banana.WX

{-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Main
------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
data AppState = AppState {
    count :: Int
} deriving (Show)

type String = [Char]

main :: IO ()
main = start $ do
    f        <- frame [text := "AppState"]
    myButton <- button f [text := "Go"]
    output   <- staticText f []

    set f [layout := margin 10 $
            column 5 [widget myButton, widget output]]

    let networkDescription :: forall t. Frameworks t => Moment t ()
        networkDescription = do

        ebt   <- event0 myButton command

        remoteValueB <- fromPoll getRemoteApiValue
        myRemoteValue <- changes remoteValueB

        let            
            doSomeTransformation :: AppState -> AppState
            doSomeTransformation ast = ast { count = count ast }

            coreOfTheApp :: Behavior t AppState
            coreOfTheApp = accumB initialState $ (doSomeTransformation to combine with myRemoteValue) <$ ebt

        sink output [text :== show <$> coreOfTheApp]

    network <- compile networkDescription    
    actuate network

getRemoteApiValue :: IO Int
getRemoteApiValue = return 5
```

and the cabal conf:

```hs
name:                brg
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            sample frp gui
-- description:
license:             PublicDomain
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              me
maintainer:          me@gmail.com
-- copyright:
category:            fun
build-type:          Simple
-- extra-source-files:
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable bgr
  main-is:             Main.hs
  -- other-modules:
  -- other-extensions:
  build-depends:       base >=4.7 && <4.8
                       , text
                       , wx ==0.92.0.0
                       , wxcore ==0.92.0.0
                       , transformers-base
                       , reactive-banana >=0.9 && <0.10
                       , reactive-banana-wx ==0.9.0.2
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  ghc-options:         -Wall -O2
```

My problem here is how to compose `doSomeTransformation` and `myRemoteValue` in a way that I can use the remote API value as normal event value.
`changes` from banana-reactive has the following signature:

```hs
changes :: Frameworks t => Behavior t a -> Moment t (Event t (Future a))
```

which it will wrap my `IO Int` from `getRemoteApiValue`.

So basically how can I go from:

```hs
IO Int -> Moment t (Event t (Future AppState)) -> AppState
```

?

BTW I am not sure if it is cleaner having this different function signature:
`doSomeTransformation :: Int -> AppState -> AppState`, where the `Int` value is represented by the API returned value. It sounds like two `Behavior`s and one stream. Maybe a bad way to solve the problem?

Comment: how about if you provided a self contained reproduction of the problem? an FP Complete project perhaps, or at least a full self contained source code.

Comment: One of the things I am trying to understand about Haskell and fp in general is if it is sometimes enough giving functions signatures to describe the problem itself. Anyway I will try to write something in fpcomplete.

Comment: Enough to describe the problem is not the same as enough to reproduce and play with the problem in a sandbox.

Comment: I have created a project on fpcomplete although I cannot get the cabal conf to work

Comment: hmm it looks it is just this: `accumB initialState $ doSomeTransformation <$ (remoteValueB <@ myButton)`

Comment: So did you resolve this? If yes, be sure to post it as an answer not just comment.

Comment: No, it didn't solve. If it compiles doesn't meant it work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90747/discussion-between-erik-allik-and-randomize).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** the transform function needs to take one more argument, the value from the API:

```hs
transformState v (AppState x) = AppState $ x + v
```

and you need to use `<$>` (i.e. apply function) instead of `<$` (i.e. overwrite with constant value):

```hs
accumB (AppState 0) $ transformState <$> remoteValueB <@ ebt
```

**Long answer:**

*Note: I've renamed/changed a few things so please read my explanation accordingly*

What needs to be changed is the way you fold over the incoming values using `accumB`. The way `accumB` works is that it applies a sequence of functions `a -> a` to a seed value `a`, to compute a final value of type `a`. The way you are currently folding over the API values is by always applying the app state count increment function to the initial state, completely throwing away the incoming value (by using `<$`). Instead you need to *map* the incoming value not *replace* it, using `<$>`. What do you need to map the value to? A function (as per the type of `accumB`)! And that function is `transformValue eventValue :: AppState -> AppState`.

A lists and folds based example:

```hs
*Frp> data State = State Int deriving Show
*Frp> let transform x (State c) = State $ x + c
*Frp> let xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                       -- the API values
*Frp> let xsE = transform <$> xs :: [State -> State] -- the event stream
*Frp> let accumB = foldr ($)
*Frp> accumB (State 0) xsE
State 15
```

(don't forget that `a <$> b` is the same as `fmap a b`, or just `map a b` in the case of lists)

Now consider how you are currently "overwriting" any events from `remoteValueB <@ ebt` with the (function) constant `transformState`, which means that all the overwritten events that arrive always hold the same content: the `transformState` function.

Instead, what you want is to map the incoming values to some actual functions, for example one that takes the old state and combine it to the arrived value and yields a new state value:

```hs
remoteValueE :: Event t Int
remoteValueE = remoteValueB <@ ebt

transformsE :: Event t (AppState -> AppState)
transformsE = transformState <$> remoteValueE

coreOfTheApp :: Behavior t AppState
coreOfTheApp = accumB initialState $ transformsE
```

I've also changed `getRemoteApiValue` to return a changing value to imitate a real API. So with some modifications to your code, here's something that works:

```hs
import System.Random

type RemoteValue = Int

-- generate a random value within [0, 10)
getRemoteApiValue :: IO RemoteValue
getRemoteApiValue = (`mod` 10) <$> randomIO

data AppState = AppState { count :: Int } deriving Show

transformState :: RemoteValue -> AppState -> AppState
transformState v (AppState x) = AppState $ x + v

main :: IO ()
main = start $ do
    f        <- frame [text := "AppState"]
    myButton <- button f [text := "Go"]
    output   <- staticText f []

    set f [layout := minsize (sz 300 200)
                   $ margin 10
                   $ column 5 [widget myButton, widget output]]

    let networkDescription :: forall t. Frameworks t => Moment t ()
        networkDescription = do    
          ebt <- event0 myButton command

          remoteValueB <- fromPoll getRemoteApiValue
          myRemoteValue <- changes remoteValueB

          let
            events = transformState <$> remoteValueB <@ ebt

            coreOfTheApp :: Behavior t AppState
            coreOfTheApp = accumB (AppState 0) events

          sink output [text :== show <$> coreOfTheApp] 

    network <- compile networkDescription    
    actuate network
```