# How to run Haskell on OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, haskell

I just upgraded to Mac OSX El Capitan yesterday, finding that the method I used to run Haskell on terminal do not work anymore.

I used to run Haskell on terminal by typing`cd (the path where my .hs file is in)`, then type `ghci`, and finally type `:l (.hs file name)`

But it told me that `-bash: ghci: command not found` when typing `ghci`.

So how could I run Haskell on El Capitan? I am not familiar with computer and am just learning some algorithms occasionally for fun, so please avoid technical terms and give me some clear steps to follow.

(I don't know wether it helps or not, I found this [links](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3n2dmj/candidate_haskell_platform_7102a_for_use_with_os/), it suggests there is no need to reinstall the whole platform, but I don't know how to download and run the executable file it attached from github.)

Comment: @jaket I typed `./ghci` and got the same result `-bash: ./ghci: No such file or directory`

Comment: @zenith I downloaded a package from https://www.haskell.org on August, installing it and then it is fine.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. It looks like the symlinks are not created in /usr/bin but you can find the binary only in /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.10.2-x86_64/usr/bin/

Comment: I remembered I also installed some `Command line tools (OSX 10.10) for Xcode` from app store in order to run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Haskell used to install itself to `/usr/bin`, which is incompatible with the new security features in El Capitan. Thus the El Capitan installer simply removed everything in `/usr/bin` that doesn't belong there.

The new Haskell installer in [your link](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3n2dmj/candidate_haskell_platform_7102a_for_use_with_os/) provides an alternative that correctly installs to the normal `/usr/local/bin` path. You can use it. Here are the instructions:

1. Download [the installer](http://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eplatform/7.10.2/Haskell%20Platform%207.10.2-a1%2064bit-unsigned.pkg).
2. Right-click and select "Open".
3. Select "Open" again in the dialog box.

If you don't want to reinstall the whole Haskell platform, you can simply run [the script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mzero/haskell-platform/master/hptool/os-extras/osx/bin/activate-hs) from the same post, e.g. with the following command:

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mzero/haskell-platform/master/hptool/os-extras/osx/bin/activate-hs | sh
```

Comment: I coped and pasted `curl -fsSL ... | sh` in the terminal, but it says
 `You must be root to activate a particular Haskell Platform.
Please rerun this command sudo:
    sudo sh 
`

Comment: Replace `sh` with `sudo sh`.

Comment: It says `WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.` Is this OK? I am a little bit afraid since I have no idea what am I doing.

Comment: Yes that warning is correct, you shouldn't use `sudo` when you don't know what you're doing. If possible, just reinstall the whole Haskell platform from scratch to avoid `sudo`.

Comment: I will try reinstalling it. But since the previous version still exists, will this make my Haskell-related file bigger and bigger with most of it being redundancy?

Comment: @CYC: well, just download the script, and execute it as root!

Comment: I just tried piping the curl command to `sudo sh` and it tried to add all the symlinks to `/usr/bin/`, so that's not a complete solution. Looking in that script it doesn't seem like it can easily be modified to use `/usr/local` instead of `/usr` either.

Answer (score 2):

If you had Haskell installed before the upgrade, you don't need to reinstall it.

For some reason the `activate-hs` script mentioned in the other solutions tries to create the symlinks in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/share`, which will fail because of SIP (I can't understand why the script does this).

However this script can easily be amended to create the symlinks in `/usr/local/` instead. I have put an edited version of the script [here](https://gist.github.com/johnjcamilleri/1ed5db5eb4bd26a97afb#file-activate-hs-L283-L289) (see lines 283 to 289).

If you are lazy and blindly trust me, you can just run the following:

```
curl -fsSL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnjcamilleri/1ed5db5eb4bd26a97afb/raw/654eda72af4cdb6f47f4fad3c7d7823449716007/activate-hs | sudo sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/share before installing it.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Haskell for Mac. http://haskellformac.com/

A nice Haskell IDE for Mac. No configuration, package management, etc. required.