# Install Agda on OSX El Capitan?

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal, agda

I was trying to instal Agda on my mac, following the instructions http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.MacOSX

But I get some problems:

1. When I typed `cabal update` in a Terminal window, it says `Skipping download: Local and remote files match.` I am not sure it means it worked or not.
2. I can't find my `.bash_profile` file, so I don't know how to update my `PATH variable`.
3. If I tried just skipping the first two steps above, typing `cabal install happy alex` directly, and it says the following:

   ```
   Resolving dependencies...
   Configuring alex-3.1.7...
   Configuring happy-1.19.5...
   Building happy-1.19.5...
   Building alex-3.1.7...
   Failed to install happy-1.19.5
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/happy-1.19.5.log ):
   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/bh/q7b8bhkj3bq8s6ml5zxvwfd40000gn/T/cabal-tmp-28407/happy-1.19.5/dist/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/bh/q7b8bhkj3bq8s6ml5zxvwfd40000gn/T/cabal-tmp-28407/happy-1.19.5/dist/setup/Main.o )
   Linking /var/folders/bh/q7b8bhkj3bq8s6ml5zxvwfd40000gn/T/cabal-tmp-28407/happy-1.19.5/dist/setup/setup ...
   Configuring happy-1.19.5...
   Building happy-1.19.5...
   Preprocessing executable 'happy' for happy-1.19.5...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id mtl-2.2.1-7fee06b00eebbe3fa92f6d82f0fb6c19
       (use -v for more information)
   Failed to install alex-3.1.7
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/alex-3.1.7.log ):
   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/bh/q7b8bhkj3bq8s6ml5zxvwfd40000gn/T/cabal-tmp-28406/alex-3.1.7/dist/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/bh/q7b8bhkj3bq8s6ml5zxvwfd40000gn/T/cabal-tmp-28406/alex-3.1.7/dist/setup/Main.o )
   Linking /var/folders/bh/q7b8bhkj3bq8s6ml5zxvwfd40000gn/T/cabal-tmp-28406/alex-3.1.7/dist/setup/setup ...
   Configuring alex-3.1.7...
   Building alex-3.1.7...
   Preprocessing executable 'alex' for alex-3.1.7...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id QuickCheck-2.8.1-720f6faecb50e002ef05e66ef82b9675
       (use -v for more information)
   cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
   alex-3.1.7 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   happy-1.19.5 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   ```

   I think this means something failed, but I don't know what to do. Help please.

**EDIT**:

4. If I type `cabal install agda` directly, it gives me the following error:

   ```
   Resolving dependencies...
   Downloading EdisonAPI-1.3...
   Downloading QuickCheck-2.8.2...
   Configuring QuickCheck-2.8.2...
   Downloading STMonadTrans-0.3.3...
   Configuring EdisonAPI-1.3...
   Downloading boxes-0.1.4...
   Configuring boxes-0.1.4...
   Downloading data-hash-0.2.0.1...
   Downloading edit-distance-0.2.2.1...
   Configuring STMonadTrans-0.3.3...
   Downloading geniplate-mirror-0.7.4...
   Downloading hashtables-1.2.1.0...
   Downloading monadplus-1.4.2...
   Downloading polyparse-1.12...
   Downloading strict-0.3.2...
   Downloading unix-compat-0.4.2.0...
   Building boxes-0.1.4...
   Building QuickCheck-2.8.2...
   Building STMonadTrans-0.3.3...
   Failed to install QuickCheck-2.8.2
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/QuickCheck-2.8.2.log ):
   [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/bh/q7b8bhkj3bq8s6ml5zxvwfd40000gn/T/cabal-tmp-29102/QuickCheck-2.8.2/dist/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/bh/q7b8bhkj3bq8s6ml5zxvwfd40000gn/T/cabal-tmp-29102/QuickCheck-2.8.2/dist/setup/Main.o )
   Linking /var/folders/bh/q7b8bhkj3bq8s6ml5zxvwfd40000gn/T/cabal-tmp-29102/QuickCheck-2.8.2/dist/setup/setup ...
   Configuring QuickCheck-2.8.2...
   Building QuickCheck-2.8.2...
   Preprocessing library QuickCheck-2.8.2...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id random-1.1-1229fa9ea3f9951a38fad637630a5acf
       (use -v for more information)
   Building EdisonAPI-1.3...
   Failed to install STMonadTrans-0.3.3
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/STMonadTrans-0.3.3.log ):
   Configuring STMonadTrans-0.3.3...
   Building STMonadTrans-0.3.3...
   Preprocessing library STMonadTrans-0.3.3...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id mtl-2.2.1-7fee06b00eebbe3fa92f6d82f0fb6c19
       (use -v for more information)
   Failed to install boxes-0.1.4
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/boxes-0.1.4.log ):
   Configuring boxes-0.1.4...
   Building boxes-0.1.4...
   Preprocessing library boxes-0.1.4...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id split-0.2.2-bdc181dc0cb027cda71092df3fe3fb02
       (use -v for more information)
   Configuring data-hash-0.2.0.1...
   Configuring edit-distance-0.2.2.1...
   Configuring geniplate-mirror-0.7.4...
   Configuring monadplus-1.4.2...
   Failed to install EdisonAPI-1.3
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/EdisonAPI-1.3.log ):
   Configuring EdisonAPI-1.3...
   Building EdisonAPI-1.3...
   Preprocessing library EdisonAPI-1.3...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id mtl-2.2.1-7fee06b00eebbe3fa92f6d82f0fb6c19
       (use -v for more information)
   Building data-hash-0.2.0.1...
   Building edit-distance-0.2.2.1...
   Building geniplate-mirror-0.7.4...
   Building monadplus-1.4.2...
   Configuring hashtables-1.2.1.0...
   Failed to install edit-distance-0.2.2.1
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/edit-distance-0.2.2.1.log ):
   Configuring edit-distance-0.2.2.1...
   Building edit-distance-0.2.2.1...
   Preprocessing library edit-distance-0.2.2.1...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id random-1.1-1229fa9ea3f9951a38fad637630a5acf
       (use -v for more information)
   Configuring unix-compat-0.4.2.0...
   Failed to install geniplate-mirror-0.7.4
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/geniplate-mirror-0.7.4.log ):
   Configuring geniplate-mirror-0.7.4...
   Building geniplate-mirror-0.7.4...
   Preprocessing library geniplate-mirror-0.7.4...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id mtl-2.2.1-7fee06b00eebbe3fa92f6d82f0fb6c19
       (use -v for more information)
   Building unix-compat-0.4.2.0...
   Building hashtables-1.2.1.0...
   Configuring polyparse-1.12...
   Failed to install hashtables-1.2.1.0
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/hashtables-1.2.1.0.log ):
   Configuring hashtables-1.2.1.0...
   Building hashtables-1.2.1.0...
   Preprocessing library hashtables-1.2.1.0...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id hashable-1.2.3.3-09c4177c49dd46a63f7036317bb17114
       (use -v for more information)
   Building polyparse-1.12...
   Configuring strict-0.3.2...
   Failed to install polyparse-1.12
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/polyparse-1.12.log ):
   Configuring polyparse-1.12...
   Building polyparse-1.12...
   Preprocessing library polyparse-1.12...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id text-1.2.1.3-3718968f98d5614ccdc45c27d4e8b0a1
       (use -v for more information)
   Building strict-0.3.2...
   Installed monadplus-1.4.2
   Installed unix-compat-0.4.2.0
   Downloading filemanip-0.3.6.3...
   Configuring filemanip-0.3.6.3...
   Building filemanip-0.3.6.3...
   Failed to install filemanip-0.3.6.3
   Build log ( /Users/ChiuYenChao/.cabal/logs/filemanip-0.3.6.3.log ):
   Configuring filemanip-0.3.6.3...
   Building filemanip-0.3.6.3...
   Preprocessing library filemanip-0.3.6.3...
   <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id mtl-2.2.1-7fee06b00eebbe3fa92f6d82f0fb6c19
       (use -v for more information)
   Installed data-hash-0.2.0.1
   Installed strict-0.3.2
   Updating documentation index
   /Users/ChiuYenChao/Library/Haskell/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2/index.html
   cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
   Agda-2.5.1.1 depends on filemanip-0.3.6.3 which failed to install.
   EdisonAPI-1.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   EdisonCore-1.3.1.1 depends on EdisonAPI-1.3 which failed to install.
   QuickCheck-2.8.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   STMonadTrans-0.3.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   boxes-0.1.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   cpphs-1.20.1 depends on polyparse-1.12 which failed to install.
   edit-distance-0.2.2.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   equivalence-0.3.1 depends on STMonadTrans-0.3.3 which failed to install.
   filemanip-0.3.6.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   geniplate-mirror-0.7.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   hashtables-1.2.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   haskell-src-exts-1.17.1 depends on polyparse-1.12 which failed to install.
   polyparse-1.12 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
   ```

Comment: You may already have `happy` and `alex` on your system. How did you install Haskell in the first place?

Comment: @ErikR  It seems you are right, I can find `happy` and `alex` in my `bin` file fold, but I still can't proceed the `cabal install agra` step. P.S. I installed something called `unsigned`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920452/how-to-run-haskell-on-osx-el-capitan) when upgraded to OSX El Captain.

Comment: You might like [Agda Writer](https://github.com/markokoleznik/agda-writer). Though, it wasn't updated for months.

Comment: Which version of the Haskell Platform do you have installed?

Comment: @ErikR version 7.10.2

Comment: I know this is probably not what you are looking for but I would recommend you try and remove the HP, install stack and then try it - btw: if you cannot find the `.bash_profile` it's either because it's *hidden* (well not really but you know terminals and stuff won't show files beginning with `.` by default) so you just don't see it or it's really not there in this case you can simply create it (see http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/sample-mac-osx-bashrc-terminal-startup-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After failing numerous times, I just uninstall the old version Haskell and reinstall it, and then the http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.MacOSX method works pretty well...

Answer (score 4):

I would try building Agda with stack.

1. Download `stack` for OSX using [these instructions](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#mac-os-x)
2. Run:

   ```
   stack setup
   stack install Agda
   ```

Both steps might take a while. Watch the output to see where stack places the Agda programs - it probably will be something like `~/.local/bin`

**Update**

Some explanation of the $PATH environment variable and how to set it:

- https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/
- https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: I am trying `Manual download`, but have no idea what does `$PATH` mean, how to set it and how do I know where is `the same directory where stack itself will install executables`?