# reactive-banana how to do IO events correctly

Tags: reactive-banana

Based on my previous question whose setting I refined gradually ([How to create monadic behaviour in reactive-banana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088279/how-to-create-monadic-behaviour-in-reactive-banana)):

Suppose there is `eKey`, an event fired whenever a key is pressed, `b` of type `Buffer` which is modified appropriately whenever a supported event occurs in `eKey`, and finally there are `IO` actions to be taken on some of the events. These `IO` actions depend on the state of `b` (for simplicity assume they print the current state of `b` to the console).

Currently, I have this to select the action that happens on an event:

```
getKeyAction :: KeyVal -> Maybe (IO Buffer -> IO Buffer)
getKeyAction 65288 = Just . liftM $ backspace
getKeyAction 65293 = Just $ \mb -> do
    b <- mb
    print $ "PRESSED ENTER: " ++ toString b
    return emptyBuffer
getKeyAction 65360 = Just . liftM $ leftMost
getKeyAction 65361 = Just . liftM $ left
...
getKeyAction _     = Nothing
```

and then I do:

```
let
    eBufferActions = filterJust $ getKeyAction <$> eKey
    bBuffer        = accumB (return emptyBuffer) eBufferActions -- model `b`
eBuffer <- changes bBuffer
reactimate' $ fmap displayBuffer <$> eBuffer
```

for some `displayBuffer :: IO Buffer -> IO ()`.

It does not seem to work as intended. The state of `bBuffer` seems to be evaluated on every event anew (effectively running all `IO` actions collected thus far every time an event occurs) which makes sense when I think about it in retrospect.

How should I refactor my code to do this correctly? (i.e. `IO` actions see current state of the buffer, nothing except the buffer gets accumulated)

---

If I could construct an `Event` that bears value of the `bBuffer` on occasion of an appropriate `eKey` event, then I could simply map my a dedicated `IO` action over it and `reactimate`. What do you think? How to do that? Would `<@` achieve what I am trying to do? But how would I postpone the current change to `b` associated with the current key press after I take snapshot of `b` with `<@` to map the `Buffer -> IO ()` over it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I believe this solves my problem, but I am not sure it is the right thing to do. So please comment.

1. I factor out those actions that do some non-trivial `IO` (other than `return`)
2. I filter the `eKey` event into two: `eBuffer` and `eConfirm`

   1. `eBuffer` collects all modifying events (including clearing the buffer on confirmation)
   2. `eConfirm` collects all confirmation events
3. I tag `eConfirm` with values of `bBuffer`, which captures the evolution of the buffer
4. Finally, I `reactimate` separately the `IO` and the `changes` of the buffer

The code fragment:

```
getKeyAction :: KeyVal -> Maybe (Buffer -> Buffer)
getKeyAction 65288 = Just backspace
-- omit action for ENTER
...


getConfirm :: KeyVal -> Maybe (Buffer -> Buffer)
getConfirm 65293 = Just (const mkBuffer) -- Clear buffer on ENTER
getConfirm _     = Nothing
```

Then in the description of the network:

```
let
    eBuffer  = filterJust $ getKeyAction <$> eKey
    eConfirm = filterJust $ getConfirm   <$> eKey
    bBuffer  = accumB mkBuffer $ unions [ eBuffer, eConfirm ]
    eEval    = bBuffer <@ eConfirm

eBufferChanges <- changes bBuffer

reactimate  $         evalBuffer <$> eEval
reactimate' $ fmap displayBuffer <$> eBufferChanges
```

for `evalBuffer :: Buffer -> IO ()` and `displayBuffer :: Buffer -> IO ()`.

Comment: Looks good to me. Step 1 is the key to everything. That said, I'm a little confused about your naming conventions. Why do you call it `evalBuffer`? As far as I understand, `Buffer` is an immutable value, which you change by applying pure functions `Buffer -> Buffer`.

Comment: `evalBuffer` is an `IO` action that takes the "current" state of `Buffer` and evaluates it (sends the buffer to an interpreter and that prints a result to console). If you meant `eEval` those are the events that require evaluation. I personally do not stand by this naming, it was just the first idea I had.